# Showing there are no integer solution to equation $\;2^x = 4y+3$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am stuck on this problem and I'm not sure how to approach it. Can anyone help me out with figuring how to approach the proof?

My task is to:

> Prove that it is impossible to find integers $\,x,\, y\,$ such that $\;2^x = 4y + 3$.

I assumed a proof by cases would be the way to go?

Any input? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not immediately clear how a proof by cases would help, besides, perhaps, considering $x,y$ each modulo some pithy number. I'm voting to close this as off-topic as it is not evident that you have tried the problem yourself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Proof-By-Cases - Sketch:**

We consider $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. For all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$:

1. $x > 0$
2. $x = 0,\;$ or
3. $x < 0$

$(1)$ For non-negative integer $x (x >0)$: Show the left hand side will always be even, except when $x = 0$, and the right hand side will always be odd, regardless of the integer value of $y$.
(I.e. all *positive* integral powers of $2$ are even, but $4y+3 = 2\cdot 2 y + 2 + 1 = 2(2y+1) + 1$ must be odd, regardless of the value of $y$.)

$(2)$ Then consider the case $x = 0$: $\;2^0 = 1 \neq 4y+3 = 2(2y+1) + 1$, whatever the *integer* value of $y$.

$(3)$ For negative integers $x (x < 0):$ the left-hand side will *not be an integer* $\left(\text{e.g.,}\;\; 2^{-2} = \dfrac 14\right),\;$ while the right hand side will *always* be an integer, regardless of the value of integer $y$. Hence the equation has not solution in integers in this case, either.

---

And hence we conclude there are no integer solutions for $x, y$ satisfying the equation: $$2^x = 4y + 3$$

Comment: That would be considered proof by cases wouldn't it? :S

Comment: Yes, it would: consider all scenarios: prove in each case, no solution exists.

Comment: @theolc Not really. You can write the proof as: $4y+3$ is odd thus $2^x$ is odd integer, thus $x=0$ contradiction....

Comment: @N.S.: The proof as sketched by amWhy **is** by cases; what you mean is that it can be reorganized to have a different structure.

Answer (score 1):

$2^x$ is even and $4 y+3$ is odd...

Comment: What if $x < 0$? Also, 1 is not even.

Comment: @Arkamis If $x<0$, $2^x$ is not an integer and if $x=0$, it is one and the other side cannot be one...